# Merge Fields into one Row with a Query

Tags: ms-access, merge

I am working with Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.  What I am trying to figure out is how to merge all characters for each DOMAIN field into one row, for example:

```
Q01                         DOMAIN      Q32
-----------------------------------------------
http://redbull.example.com  example.com F
http://www.example.com      example.com B
```

What I would like to accomplish through a query is to take the DOMAIN field and create a view which merges the "Q32" into one row, for example:

```
DOMAIN      Q32
----------------
example.com B F
```

Is this possible through a design query or would I have to write a SQL statement?  I tried the following SQL statement to create a UNION with two different tables, though I still didn't get the merge displayed correctly.

```
SELECT DOMAIN, Q32
FROM tblMERGE
UNION
SELECT DOMAIN, Q32
FROM tblASSET;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not more than 2 values for domain, this will help:

```
SELECT [DOMAIN], IIF(First([Q32])<>Last([Q32]), First([Q32])+' '+Last([Q32]),First(Q32)) AS _Q32
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [DOMAIN];
```